# transforming XML to text (csv file) sorting by attribute

Tags: xml, sorting, csv, xslt, saxon

I'm new to XSLT 2.0 and I have to transform XML into a text file (CSV), but I want the output to be in the line attribute order (see below the XML, the stylesheet and the output). As you can see the output of line="9" should be the 2nd line. The question is how can I change the stylesheet to achieve the right output?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <MP>        
        <CSVIMP line="10" content="xyz"/>
        <CSVIMP line="11" content="123"/>
        <CSVIMP line="8" content="123"/>
    </MP>
    <MP>
        <CSVIMP line="9" content="abc"/>
        <CSVIMP line="12" content="456"/>
    </MP>
</root>
```

My stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:template match="MP">
        <xsl:for-each select="CSVIMP">
            <xsl:sort select="./@line" data-type="number"></xsl:sort>
            <xsl:value-of select="./@line"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="./@content"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"></xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Transformed output (Saxon 9.5 HE):

```
8,123
10,xyz
11,123
9,abc
12,456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what you want without seeing the expected output. Since you say that "*the output of line="9" should be the 2nd line*, I guess you want to do this (and only this):

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="MP/CSVIMP">
        <xsl:sort select="./@line" data-type="number"></xsl:sort>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@line"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@content"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

And since you're using XSLT 2.0, you could probably* shorten the whole thing to:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="MP/CSVIMP">
        <xsl:sort select="./@line" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@line, @content" separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

(*) assuming all `CSVIMP` elements have both attributes.